# Better time-out detection for synchronous operations

Tags: c#, timeout, threadpool, synchronous, begininvoke

I need a way to perform some action synchronously which should complete in half a second, but might just hang around for minutes. If it times out I don't care about the result. Here's the I'm doing it right now using compiler-generated delegate.BeginInvoke:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool disposed = false;
    var wait = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var a = new Action(
        () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // <- some looong action

                if (!disposed)
                    lock (wait)
                        if (!disposed)
                            wait.Set();
            });

    a.BeginInvoke(a.EndInvoke, null);

    bool success = wait.WaitOne(500);
    Console.WriteLine(success ? "success" : "timeout");

    lock (wait)
    {
        wait.Dispose();
        disposed = true;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Looks ugly. And I'm aware lambda closure's `disposed` variable is modified (unlike my ReSharper, I like this C# feature). All because I want to dispose `ManualResetEvent`. Can you suggest better approach in .NET4? Perhaps should I just skip disposing the event and rely on GC?

One note: `ManualResetEvent.Set()` explodes if you try to do it on disposed instance.

Comment: Calling BeginInvoke is how you start an Asynchronous operation, not a Synchronous one.

Comment: Right, but I want to complete it synchronously within time-out interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh, now that I looked a bit more at code samples using compiler-generated `delegate.BeginInvoke` I see that it returns `IAsyncResult` which has `AsyncWaitHandle` exactly for my goal:

```
var a = new Action(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)); // <- some looong action
IAsyncResult asyncResult = a.BeginInvoke(a.EndInvoke, null);
bool success = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(500);
```

That wait handle in case of `AsyncResult` is in fact an instance of `ManualResetEvent` which is disposed automatically from thread-pool thread right when my asynchronous call completes.

Comment: Yup.  But no real difference, only EndInvoke() can dispose it.  Which you can't call if the wait timed-out.  Don't bother, kernel events are dirt cheap and peanuts compared to that thread you kept running.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not skip the calling of the Dispose and rely on the GC.  It's a waste of resources, plain and simple.

In .NET 4.0 I'd take a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), which is in the System.Threading assembly, new to 4.0.

Specifically, look at the [Task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) as well as the [Wait method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235604(v=VS.100).aspx), which will allow you to specify a timeout.

Also, you will want to look at how to [cancel a Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=VS.100).aspx) in the event it times out.